# Can I check balance on data on T-Mobile SIM card (Poland)?

Tags: cellphones, poland

I contacted T-Mobile's SIM card in Poland, which is 25 PLN (5 PLN sign-up fee and 20 PLN top-up which is valid for 30 days). It includes 10 GB data package.

Now, I would like to check how much data remain available right now. I send `*101#` but it seems to show only the balance in terms of deposit money (which is 0 PLN in my case), and doesn't show how much data is left in my account available. I don't read Polish so it might be wrong, though.

So is it possible to check the balance on data?

---

[image]

Comment: Just curious, can you post what it says in Polish?

Comment: @Kuba Sure. Updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the current status using: ***140*265*1#**

To check your EU allowance try: ***140*360#**

You can also download their free "Mój T-mobile" app which shows all of this info in a nice way.

https://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/m%C3%B3j-t-mobile/id495153613?mt=8